# How to change drawer width of Vaadin App Layout

Tags: css, vaadin, styling

In Vaadin 23, how to increase or decrease the width of the drawer area of a Vaadin [App Layout component](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/ds/components/app-layout)?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In your global style sheet, for example `frontend/themes/mytheme/styles.css` (this assumes you have a custom theme annotation defined `@Theme("mytheme")`), add the following:

```css
vaadin-app-layout::part(drawer) {
  width: 300px;
}
```

This is slightly simpler than the solution that Tarek suggested (which also works just fine).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to style the internals of the `app-layout` component.

If the project is using the [custom-theme mechanism](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/ds/customization/custom-theme), then create a file called `vaadin-app-layout.css` under the directory `frontend/themes/<Your-Theme-Name>/components`. In that file, you can, say, increase the width of the AppLayout drawer like so:

```css
:host {
    --vaadin-app-layout-drawer-offset-size: 400px;
}

[part="drawer"] {
    width: var(--vaadin-app-layout-drawer-offset-size);
}
```

NOTE: if you are *not* using the custom-theme mechanism, then you will need to add the aforementioned styling in a CSS file that is imported using the `@CssImport` annotation. For example, you can create a file called `vaadin-app-layout.css` under the project `frontend` directory, and then import it from java using the following annotation:

```java
@CssImport(value = "vaadin-app-layout.css", themeFor = "vaadin-app-layout")
```